# JSQMessagesViewcontroller custom JSQMediaItem

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using JSQMessagesViewController and I write my custom photo and voice MediaItems which inheritance JSQMediaItem, and the mediaView of these two message types are different.
Everything goes fine when sending/receiving these two kind of messages, but when I use a loop to load some historical messages, it appears incorrectly.

[image: screenShot1]

It seems that all the mediaMessage reused the first mediaMessage's cell size.
But when I send photo/voice messages then, the newly send message appears correctly.

[image: screenShot2]

my cellForItemAtIndexPath method is as follow:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

The message loading code:

```
for msg in msgs {
    let jsqMessage = self.genJSQMessage(msg)
    self.messages.append(jsqMessage)
    self.finishSendingMessageAnimated(true)
}
```

I am really confused, any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi mate! could you plan post a little how did you get that custom layout ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I did not override mediaHash() function in JSQMediaItem.

Comment: Great your resolved it, can you post your code for how you send record voice audio message with JSQ? Please